# Autoload issue in using Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm

cli-config.php

```php
<?php

require_once 'Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

$path = dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', __DIR__);
$classLoader->register();

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Proxies', __DIR__);
$classLoader->register();

$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache);
$config->setProxyDir(__DIR__ . '/Proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');
$driver = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver($path . '/doctrine2/default/yml');
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);

require_once $path . '/database.php';
$db = new DATABASE_CONFIG;

$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_pgsql',
    'host' => $db->default['host'],
    'user' => $db->default['login'],
    'password' => $db->default['password'],
    'dbname' => $db->default['database'],
);

$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);

$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
            'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
            'dialog' => new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DialogHelper(),
            'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
        ));
```

With these settings, I could successfully generate yml and entities with following commands:

**doctrine2 orm:convert-mapping --from-database yml yml**

**doctrine2 orm:generate-entities Entities/**

When executing command "doctrine2 orm:validate-schema", it showed following errors:

**[ReflectionException]**

**Class XXX does not exist**

But I could find the XXX.php in Entities folder. I've tried to add namespace Entities, but it still couldn't find the model. Maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

well, I found the answer. Just change the commands to

doctrine2 orm:convert-mapping --namespace="Entities\" --from-database yml yml

doctrine2 orm:generate-entities .

doctrine2 orm:validate-schema

Comment: I needed to use `Entities\\\`